# problem while linking new.java to home.java

Tags: java

I have two files: `home.java` and `new. java`

When I click a button in `home.java` called "new", `new.java` should open and it is opening correctly if I am including these lines of code in `actionPerformed` method of button:

```
home newinstance = new home()
newinstance.setVisible(true);
```

Everything is going according to the plan except that the `new.java` is opening in new window and the old `home.java` is not dissapearing

I want the `new.java` to come not as new window but same window and `home.java` to disappear. (If first will occur second wil automatically occur)

Comment: It sound like you are doing a few things wrong. You should name your files as your classes are named. Eg. you save class User in file `User.java` and you can't name a class `new` because that is a reserved word in Java.

Comment: post some code please os we can help you

Comment: Also: please stop thinking of your code in terms of `.java` files, but think in case of objects and classes instead. The difference might seem subtle and small in the beginning, but it will pay off in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of both being windows (JFrame) let both be components (extend JComponent) which you put inside a single window.

```
frame.getContentPane().add(new Home());
frame.setVisible(true);

void actionPerformed() {
  frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
  frame.getContentPane().add(new New());
}
```

I'm assuming you use Swing. If you're using AWT, well...use Swing :p

(Also, classes in Java should be Capitalized, and it's a bit confusing if you refer to them as .java)

Comment: sorry for the errors :) . i am actually new to this and i am using netbeans framework to complete my work . So it is little bit confusing about contentpanes and frames and layers

Comment: @user808062 Ok, then I suggest you go and learn about those things, at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/. Then you can still use Netbeans' UI maker if you want, but it's better to have an understanding of what it does.